# check increse-decrese event input type number in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i intercept increse and decrese event in an input type numer in jquery?

now i'm using this code:

```
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
}
```

But it intercepts all clicks over the input.

Comment: Using mouse, what do you wanna do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `change()` event

```
$(":input[type='number']").bind('change', function () 
{
  console.log( "new number is " + $( this ).val() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("input[type='number']").bind(...)
```